# Как абстрагировать модель от базы данных в MVVM

Tags: алгоритм, шаблоны-проектирования

В мой проект очень хорошо ложиться паттерн MVVM. Но есть большая хотелка размером с небоскреб. Сделать мое приложение способным работать одновременно с разными базами данных. Как ловчее абстрагировать при применении данного паттерна работу с базой данных от ViewModel?

Comment: Например сделать свою VM в виде враппера. Она будет иметь только общие поля, само по себе поле может быть например вот таким -  CustomProperty<T> и через рефлексию у доменной модели брать его тип и класть в CustomProperty<T>.Value.